# For Each view pushing content away

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on a profile page and it has to render a list of previous runs and so I'm using a for each to do that. But for some reason, this view pushes all the other information out of view and I'm not sure why. Screenshot of the issue:

[image: Content overflowing vertically]

Here's the code:

```
struct AccountView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    @State var isShowingAccountDetails = false
    @ObservedObject var tracks = RunsService()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            AccountHeader(tracks: tracks)
            Text("This Week")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .padding(.leading)
            PersonalWeeklyCard()
                .frame(height: 150)
                .padding(.horizontal)
            Text("Previous runs")
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .padding(.leading)
            Spacer()
            VStack{
                
                ForEach(tracks.myRuns, id: \.id) { track in
                    RunCard(track: track)
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: tracks.fetchRuns)
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(action: {
            isShowingAccountDetails = true
        }, label: {Text("Details")}))
        .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingAccountDetails) {
            AccountDetails(session: session)
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You are wrapping everything inside a VStack. The content is way to much for this page. Use a ScrollView or use less content